# django taggit similar_objects problem(maybe queryset)

Tags: python, django, tags

Currently, when searching for a tag like Instagram, an image list page including the tag has been created. I wanted to list the related tag list in one line here, and I found out that the 'taggit' package already has a good function called 'similar_objects'. My 'view.py' is designed to expose only certain tags as follows. If you add "similar_objects,"
"'ImageTagListView' object has no attribute 'object'" occurs.
I think it's a "queryset" problem. Please tell me the solution. Thank you in advance.

class ImageTagListView(ImageListView):

```
template_name = 'imageapp/taglist.html'
model = Image

def get_queryset(self):
    return Image.objects.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs.get('tag'))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tagname'] = self.kwargs['tag']
    context["related_items"] = self.object.tags.similar_objects()[:4]

    return context
```

Comment: This is a *listview*, hence there is no `object, since it deals with a *collection* of objects.

Comment: Thank you. Then, how can we solve this problem? Is there any way to do it on the Listview?